# is there a way to send cppcheck results to slack?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, slack

I just started using cppcheck, and I was wondering if there is any way to access to the report values (for instance number of total errors) and send it to slack. I have been searching in the documentation and here in SO but I have found nothing, as I just have been using Jenkins for a couple of months ( I am a junior dev) I was wondering if somebody know if this is possible and could drive me in the right direction.